# How to tell if a map is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying for my test tomorrow and am getting stuck on this question in the study guide. My teacher posted the answer key so I don't just need the answer I'm really looking for how to get to the answer with this specific case? Normally I don't have trouble with these but something about the cubic part is making me confused. Thank you in advance!
[image: This is the problem]

Comment: Would you know how to solve this problem if the map were instead
$$
(a,b,c,d) \mapsto (c,d+c,b+a,a)?
$$

Comment: Yes! And I figured the posted problem out as well - thank you! @BenGrossmann

Comment: @BenGrossmann if a map is linear, does it then have to always be onto and one-to-one as well?

Comment: I does not. For example, the map $(a,b) \mapsto (a,0)$ is linear but neither onto nor one-to-one

Comment: @BenGrossmann oh I see - so it must be invertible in order for it to also be onto and one to one. If a map is an isomorphism, must it be linear/one to one/onto?

Comment: @BenGrossmann for ex, for the more simple map where the 2x2 matrix (a,b,c,d) --> ad-bc, would it be linear or onto or one to one?

Comment: Yes, a map is an "isomorphism" if and only if it is onto and one to one. The map that you describe is not a linear map

Comment: @BenGrossmann but that map also isn't an isomorphism, so can I assume that it must not be one to one or onto?

Comment: That line of reasoning is not correct. What I meant earlier is that a **linear** map is an isomorphism if and only if it is onto and one to one. Depending on your exact use of terminology, the function $(a,b,c,d) \mapsto ad - bc$ might qualify as a "function" but not as a "map".

Comment: @BenGrossmann my teacher wrote on his answer key that (,,,)↦− was not isomorphic but he didn't write if it was one-to-one or onto. Did he not specify because it wouldn't be either?

Comment: First of all, "isomorhpic" does not refer to the property of "being an isomorphism"; the correct phrasing is $(a,b,c,d)\mapsto ad-bc$ "is not an isomorphism". Second, I can't read your teacher's mind. "One-to-one" and "onto" are adjectives that can be applied to functions in addition to linear maps. The function $(a,b,c,d) \mapsto ad - bc$ is not one to one, but it is onto. I don't know why he decided not to write that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the kernel?  Well,  wait, I'm getting ahead of myself.   But you can check that it's linear.   And then that the kernel is trivial.   Since the vector spaces have the same  (finite)  dimension,  this implies that we have an isomorphism.

Another way would be to check surjectivity.

Comment: but it is not linear?

Comment: It's linear, believe it or not.   Don't be fooled by the exponents in the generic polynomial.

Comment: thank you so much! understood now